# Looking for a reference for a paper by Mordell

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

On page 384 of the book "Number Theory:Volume 1:tools and Diophantine Equations" by Henri Cohen there is reference to the fact that: "It has been proved by Schinzel, Mordell nd successors that such an identity does not exist..."

Can someone give me a reference hopefully to a paper available on the Internet.  I don't have access to Cohen's book, only to an excerpt from the book available on the Internet.

Comment: Not the question, but a useful link about Demyanenkos' result on the sum of four cubes (which Cohen discusses in the remark above): the translation: http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~hecohen/sum4cub.ps.

Answer (score 4):

Schinzel, On sums of four cubes of polynomials, JLMS 43 (1968), 143--145. http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-43/1/143.full.pdf

Mordell, On sums of four cubes of polynomials, Acta Arithmetica Volume: 16, Issue: 4, page 365-370 (1970).  http://eudml.org/doc/204934

Cohn and Mordell, On sums of four cubes of polynomials, J. London Math. Soc.(2), 5(1972) 74-78.
http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-5/1/74.full.pdf

Comment: It is J. H. E. Cohn and L. J. Mordell.

Answer (score 3):

The paper of Schinzel is "On the sums of cubes of polynomials" J. London Math. Soc. and the one by Mordell is "On sums of four cubes of polynomials" Acta Arith. 16, 365-369 (1970).